# Pydev Run configuration have to change main module manually for each file

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When I import a project into pydev. I have to manually add a run configuration. I have to hit RunAs -Python Run and select a run configuration for each file and change the main module everytime. This would not work for a package with 100 python files.

This seems not to be the case from tutorials online. 
https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm[image]
What did I do wrong?
What do I put as main module in the run configuration so that it will run the currently open python file each time?

I do not have to do this when I create a project from scratch. I hit run as - python run and it will run whatever file I currently have opened.

I am using Liclipse which is basically pydev with eclipse.

I am prompted this dialogue which was not the case before. I did add project to python path from properties. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can run by clicking Run or Debug icons. Then it asks for this

[image: Run as option in Pydev]

I select 'Python Run'. It creates a configuration for this python module with default values and automatically proceeds to run. Hope this helps.